# Erlang: How to receive a message only from a specific sender?

Tags: erlang, message-passing

In Erlang, how can I receive a message sent from a specific pid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a couple of ways:

1) Send the target process a secret code, which it can send back with all its messages:

```
-module(my).
-compile(export_all).

worker(TargetPid, Msg, SecretId) ->
     TargetPid ! {Msg, SecretId}.

get_msg(SecretId) ->
    receive
        {Msg, SecretId} -> Msg
    end. 

test() ->
    SecretId = "A1!cd!",
    spawn(my, worker, [self(), hello, "Xy*d1"]),
    spawn(my, worker, [self(), goodbye, SecretId]),

    io:format("~w~n", [get_msg(SecretId)]).
```

In the shell:

```
6> c(my).    
my.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,my}

7> my:test().
goodbye
ok

8>
```

2) Instead of matching against the secret code in the receive clause, have the target process send a message tagged with its Pid:

```
-module(my).
-compile(export_all).

get_msg(TargetPid) ->
    receive
        {Msg, TargetPid} -> Msg
    end. 

worker(TargetPid, Msg) ->
     TargetPid ! {Msg, self()}.

test() ->
    spawn(my, worker, [self(), hello]),
    Pid = spawn(my, worker, [self(), goodbye]),

    io:format("~w~n", [get_msg(Pid)]).
```

In the shell:

```
3> c(my).
my.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,my}

4> my:test().
goodbye
ok

5>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the sender's pid in the message and match against it in the receiving process.